# Joining data in a table and selecting by ID

Tags: r, join, data-manipulation

I'm doing an analysis in which I need to identify the number of land uses (mapbiomas, codes 1, 9, 15, 21...) according to the IDs of my plots. However, I can't think of a way to accomplish this.

[image]

I was hoping to find a way in which, based on the plot IDs, I could access the sum of the "areaHA" values ​​within each "mapbbiomas" code, something like this:

[image]

would you have any suggestions?

I tried grouping by ID and summarizing based on the sum of the areaHA values ​​that had mapbiomas code 1:

```r
%>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(sum(a.col.df$areaHa[a.col.df$mapbiomas=='1']))
```

however it returns me for all ID the same values

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Patrick Fernandes! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: It sounds like much of this is a merge/join operation, c.f., https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272. For dplyr, this means `*_join` functions. For the *"sum of the "areaHA" values"* part, I think it's likely https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272 should be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any dataset at hand, it is hard to say for sure. But I think you could group by both ID and biomass and then sum the area for each combination. Or do the plot IDs come from somewhere else?

```r
df |> 
  group_by(ID, mapbiomas) |> 
  summarize(sum(areaHa))
```

Comment: that way I get a table that has 3 columns (IN, mapbiomas code and area). But I still can't get what I would like. Follow my data
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1", "1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4","4"),
  mapbiomas = c("1","15","21","1","15","21","1","15","21","1","9","15","21"),
  areaHa = c("1000","15000","21000","10000","15000","21000","10000","15000","2100","10000","9000","15000","21000")
)

df